# Spring Security SAML Extension - callback for Single Log Out from Idp

Tags: spring, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am currently integrating SAML in to our web application. How do I set up my applicatoin to listen to logout request sent by IdP (when the user logout globally from another SP)?

I have read through the [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-sso.html#configuration-logout) but it doesn't talk about this scenario. It only talks about global initiated by the SP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring SAML conforms to the SAML 2.0 Single Logout profile, and the documentation says `Single Logout can be initialized from any of the participaing SPs or from the IDP.`

There's nothing extra you need to do, simply configure your IDP to send LogoutRequest to the `/saml/SingleLogout` endpoint of Spring SAML. The endpoint is defined in the default generated metadata.

Please note that only HTTP-POST and HTTP-Redirect bindings are supported for the Single Logout.

You can customize Global Logout behavior by changing `LogoutHandler` in the `SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter`.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!